# Changing Name and Description endpoint in Swagger-ui

Tags: spring, spring-data, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using Spring boot and Spring Data Rest to implement my Rest API. To document it, I have been using Swagger, with these maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would like to change and customize a bit my Swagger UI page. I want to change the name and the description it appears in the html page, concretely these names highlighted in red in the screenshot, but nothing works.

[image]

I've been trying adding the `@Api` annotation to my entities and repositories classes/interfaces, but nothing works.

Any idea about how to customize it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add an example from what you've tried?

Comment: In my entity object I tried with the next annotation: `@Entity
@Api(value="activity Name", description="activity Description")
public class Activity ` but it didn't worked. I did the same in Respository Rest interfaces, but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Api` annotation with tags and description.

```
@Api(description="Device APIs", tags = "Device")
```

Please note that `description` is deprecated but it works.